How can I install Ubuntu Server 24.04 on an Acer Aspire 5720?
I have an Acer Aspire 5720 (model ICL50), and I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS. I have tried the following:

Created a bootable USB with the amd64 Ubuntu Server 24.04 iso file using Rufus
Gone through the usual installation process (not using LVM partitions)
Same installation process but manually created MBR partitions using fdisk (200MB boot and remaining for root)
Changing SATA mode between IDE and AHCI in BIOS
Enabling and disabling D2D recovery in BIOS
Changing boot priority

But each time I try, the system will not boot and shows No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

I got this working by first using a legacy iso (Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS) from this related question.

Create a bootable USB using Rufus and the legacy iso
Set SATA mode to AHCI, D2D enabled, USB media top priority in boot order
Go through regular set up with no LVM and no need for manual partitioning
Boot into your new installation

I noticed that attempting sudo do-release-upgrade would only offer 22.04, this may be due to the recency of 24.04's release, but by using sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and setting Prompt=normal, you can successfully upgrade to Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS.
